# Why the 404 middleware behaves like this?

Tags: c#, owin, asp.net-core

Looking at the source code of ASP.NET 5 I found on the [HTTP abstractions](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions) the concrete implementation of `IApplicationBuilder`. The class has one method that's responsible for building the pipeline out of the middlewares added. The code is as bellow:

```
public RequestDelegate Build()
{
    RequestDelegate app = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    };

    foreach (var component in _components.Reverse())
    {
        app = component(app);
    }

    return app;
}
```

I got the idea: we code that request delegate returning a 404 so that if no middleware handles the request we return a 404 error. Now, suppose we code the following middleware (which is simply a `Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>`):

```
(next) => {
    RequestDelegate reqDelegate = new RequestDelegate(async context => {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        await next.Invoke(context);
    });

    return reqDelegate;
}
```

That is it returns a "Hello World" message and invokes the next piece of functionality added on the pipeline whatever that is. Now, if we simply add this with an `Use` call on `Configure` it will show "Hello World" on the screen when we request anything.

But wait a second: the 404 error middleware is being added to the pipeline anyway as the next to that one. In that case the `next.Invoke(context)` should simply return a 404. But it doesn't, that is, it shows "Hello World" with status code 200.

I've tried coding another middleware like that and adding to the pipeline and both gets called, but the 404 don't. What I'm missing here? Why the 404 is not called since he is the next to the last middleware of the pipeline?

**EDIT:** doing some tests I found something interesting. I've changed the this hello world middleware so that it just writes on the response stream if the requested path is `/helloworld`. In that case when we request `http://localhost:5000/helloworld` we get the hello world message and the 404 middleware is not called.

If, on the other hand, we request any other path, like `http://localhost:5000/test` it ignores the helloworld (as expected) and returns the 404.

In that case, it seems the 404 is just used if no middleware on the pipeline has done anything to the request/response. Is that really the case? If so, where's the code that does this?

**EDIT 2:** I've tried some more tests using the ASP.NET source code itself. I've cloned the HTTP abstractions repository locally and added to my "sources" inside `global.json` which allowed me to debug the source code. I added a breakpoint at the delegate that returns 404 and the results were as follows:

- When using IIS express the middleware isn't called. If we hit an unknown endpoint, IIS that handles, somehow the middleware is ignored.
- When using WebListener the middleware really get's called.

However, there's one strange problem: in my setting I've got one `helloWorld` middleware and one `howAreYou` middleware. The `howAreYou` is the last piece of the pipeline, and it's *next* is the 404. When I chain the 404 together and Invoke it, I get back when debugging on Fiddler an error 504 with message

> [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 158 bytes.

And debugging on VS seems that each middleware gets called twice then. I don't know if it's a bug and if it's specific to WebListener, but I really don't know how this is working.

Does that mean that when the request is handled I shouldn't call the next middleware on the pipeline? But what if I want to call the next one?

Comment: I haven't touched ASP.net 5 yet, so this is a total shot in the dark, but how do you register that second delegate? Could it be that the method you call to register it takes note that you've done something, and adds in a call to return a 200? So the 404 only applies when you don't have anything else registered?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen, I register the delegate with the `Use` method from the `ApplicationBuilder` class. I've looked at the source code, but this method just really adds the delegate to the `_components` list. Also I've searched for any checks on the number of elements of this list, but there's none also.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, I poked through the source code a bit as well. I guess re: your edit, that makes me wonder whether this cited 404 middleware *ever* gets called. Definitely strange. You said that a request to an unknown endpoint results in a 404, but I wonder whether that's the "same one," or if this one just never gets called. Not that that would make much all that much more sense, but it would be interesting to know.

Comment: To add to the mystery, the behavior isn't entirely consistent across servers, either. If you use IIS Express, you can get several codes. You'll get a 403 if you navigate to the root (e.g. localhost:5000), whereas Kestrel and self-hosting give you a 404. Changing the path for IIS to some route gives you the expected 404, but it does give you an error page rather than an empty response. That page mentions the StaticFile handler, which suggests the request has passed through ASP.NET entirely.

Comment: I've added one edit about more tests using the source code. The middleware really gets called, but just when not using IIS Express. On the other hand, when it is chained with the other middlewares, instead of just setting status code to 404 it ends up messing with the response. Now I don't know if its a bug or if I'm not understanding how this 404 should be used and I'm making a mistake on chaining it together.