# How do you get SalesforceMiddleware running with WebApi?

Tags: callback, salesforce, asp.net-web-api2, owin, middleware

I'm trying to integrate Salesforce with ASP.NET Identity login. I have been trying to use the following provider:

https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders/tree/master/src/Owin.Security.Providers.Salesforce

So I initiate the login request by redirecting the user to Salesforce, where she can login. After a succesful login, the callback URL from Salesforce should go through the provider and validate the Identity of the user.

In Startup.cs, I have added SalesforceMiddleware with the SalesforceProvider (with the available options. Callback URL is default). I want it to add Claims and Identity information about the user, and then use WebApi to redirect the callback back to my controller.

The WebApi is initialized after the SalesforceMiddleware, as I want the callback to go through the middleware, before getting redirected in my API controller. This flow is also described here ([A middleware should always invoke the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910834/a-middleware-should-always-invoke-the-next)).

If I initialize the WebApi after the middleware, all my API's stop working. So does anyone have any pointers about, what I might be doing wrong?